# Validar e alterar senha de usuário com PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentado fazer com que o código verificasse se as senhas são idênticas e caso fossem, salvasse no BD, mas não sei o que está errado que independente de ser idêntica ou não ele sempre salva.

```
 if (isset($_POST['salvar-senha'])) {

    $usr_id            = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
    $senha_atual       = md5(strip_tags($_POST['senha_atual']));
    $senha_nova        = md5(strip_tags($_POST['senha_nova']));
    $confirme_senha    = md5(strip_tags($_POST['confirme_senha']));

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT usr_password FROM users WHERE usr_login = '$usr_id' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $senha_banco = $row['usr_password'];

    if($senha_atual == "" && $senha_nova == "" && $confirme_senha == "") {
        echo "
            <script>
                alert('Os campos das senhas não podem ser nulos.');
                window.location='../configuracoes.php';
            </script>";
    } else {
        if (($senha_atual != $senha_banco) && ($senha_nova != $confirme_senha) ) {
            echo "
            <script>
                alert('As senhas não conhecidem.');
                window.location='../configuracoes.php';
            </script>";
        } else {
            if ($result=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET usr_password = '$confirme_senha' WHERE usr_id = '$usr_id' ")) {
                echo "
            <script>

                window.location='../configuracoes.php?success=yes';
            </script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem um erro de lógica aqui:

```
if (($senha_atual != $senha_banco) && ($senha_nova != $confirme_senha) )
```

Isso só é verdadeiro se a pessoa errar as duas coisas, ou seja, senha atual errada **+** senha nova e confirmação não coincidem. Em qualquer outra situação (exceto tudo em branco), a senha é gravada.

Você corrige isso considerando erro *qualquer uma* das duas situações (não ambas), portanto usando um *OU* em vez de *E*:

```
if (($senha_atual != $senha_banco) || ($senha_nova != $confirme_senha))
```

Você também pode pensar ao contrário: só é pra salvar se a senha atual estiver correta **E** as novas coincidem:

```
if (($senha_atual === $senha_banco) && ($senha_nova === $confirme_senha)) {
    // salva
```

Senão, dê uma mensagem de erro genérica (não ajude quem está tentando burlar o sistema)

```
} else {
    // erro: senha atual incorreta ou as novas não coincidem
}
```

Fora isso, o JavaScript embutido ali poderia ser substituído por *redirects* do próprio PHP, gravando as mensagens de erro na sessão.

Comment: Rapaz, fiz isso e agora só dá que as senhas não coincidem. Até se eu colocar as 3 iguais.

Comment: Tem certeza de que o md5 da senha atual bate com o que está no banco? Tentou imprimir os valores para confirmar?

Comment: Sim, tanto a senha atual bate com a do banco, como a nova senha e a confirmação também.

Answer (score 0):

Verfique sua lógica, parece estar usando o operador lógico `&& (E)` com a intenção da funcionalidade `|| (OU)`

apenas troque os operadores no primeiro e segundo `if`

uma observação sem ser grosseiro: a frase correta é "as senhas não coincidem."

Comment: Leonardo, eu nem havia reparado nesse erro, obrigado. E a propósito, o erro no PHP agora é outro, até se as 3 senhas estiverem idênticas ele diz que elas não coincidem.